# .zip corrupted on Mac

Tags: macos, compression, zip

I've got a .zip file of approx. 20GB. (20,497,570,063 bytes)

I am trying to uncompress it but both Archive Utility and Terminal are failing to do so.
Archive Utility is giving error 2 (no such file or directory).

When I execute the following command: `unzip myfile.zip` it just stops at some point, while it says that there are some extra bytes when it starts.

When I do `zipinfo` on this file, it says the same:

```
Archive:  /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/pictures.zip   20497570063   8664
warning [/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/pictures]:  17179869184 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
```

When it's done unzipping the folder is only about 8GB or so big.

Does anyone of you happen to know how I can fix this or get all the pictures out of this zip file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you could try to follow the steps in this article: [How to Repair Damaged Zip Files With Terminal](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-repair-damaged-zip-files-with-terminal--mac-49294) and see if that helps you.

Essentially what the article says is that you can try with this command:

```
zip -F myBrokenArchive.zip --out hopefullyRepairedArchive.zip
```

and if that doesn't work, make zip try even harder with

```
zip -FF myBrokenArchive.zip --out hopefullyRepairedArchive.zip
```

Comment: I had the same zip on another harddrive and that one didn't seem to be corrupted. So it's fixed anyway. But thanks for replying, I will use this in the future when I got a similar problem !

Comment: Good to hear that! An uncorrupted zip file definitely beats a repaired one. :-)

Comment: it worked so nicely

Comment: Happy to hear that, @Pranjut! 